# MySQL not recognizing variable's value when submitting a query #PHP

Tags: php, html, variables, post

Whenever I attempt to post a MySQL query, I retrieve all my variable values except for `$your_model`...which is a value I received after creating an HTML drop down list that retrieves car models in a database that belongs to the current user that is logged in.

If I do an echo before and after the "IF" statement where I am checking to see `if(isset($_POST['odo']))`, I am able to see the values of `$your_model`...but once I submit or post my odometer reading, MySQL sees the `$odo` value, the `$time` value, but not the `$your_model` value.

I've attempted to write that MySQL piece of code before, and after my code. I've attempted to nest it into different areas within the code, even nested it where I'm doing the if num_of_cars > 0

I've attempted to put `$your_model` in quotes `"$your_model"`, single quotes `'$your_model'`, wrap in in curly braces with or without quotes `{$your_model}`, `'{$your_model}'`, etc

I've also attempted `'".$your_model."'` and that did not allow MySQL to know what was in the variable

I've literally attempted every and anything I can think of, and scoured the internet. I saw a couple of forums who had similar issues...one was not resolved, and the other was solved by wrapping curly braces around the variable so that MySQL can recognize it.

I honestly believe it has something to do with the `$_POST` command...I wonder if once I submit the odometer reading to query the database, if somehow because the page refreshes, MySQL loses the value of the `$your_model` variable?

```
<?php
        require_once 'header.php';

        if (!$loggedin) die("</div></body></html>");

        if (isset($_GET['view'])) $view = sanitizeString($_GET['view']);
        else $view = $user;

        if ($view != "")
        {
                if ($view == $user) $name1 = $name2 = "Your";
                else
                {
                        $name1 = "<a href='members.php?view=$view'>$view</a>'s";
                        $name2 = "$view's";
                }

                echo "<h4>$name1 Car Portal</h4>";
                showProfile($view);

                echo "<br><br>";

                $car_query = "SELECT model FROM cars WHERE user='$user'";
                $car_result = queryMysql($car_query);
                $num_of_cars = $car_result->num_rows;

                if ($num_of_cars > 0) {
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($car_result)) {
                                $selectedModels[] = $row['model'];
                        }

                }

                if (isset($_POST['selectAModel'])) $your_model = sanitizeString($_POST['selectAModel']);


                echo <<<_END
                        <form method='post' action='car_test.php?view=$view'>
                                <select name="selectAModel">
                                <option value='Select Model'>Select A Model </option>
                _END;
                                foreach($selectedModels as $modelName) {
                                        echo "<option name='$modelName' value='$modelName'> $modelName      </option>";
                                }

                echo <<<_END
                                </select>
                                <input type='submit' name='post_car' value='Submit Car Model'>
                        </form>
                _END;

                echo "<br><br>";
                echo "<div style='text-align:center;'><h3>Your $your_model Odometer Reading</h3></div>";

                if (!isset($_POST['odo']))
                {
                        echo "<span class='info' style='color:red'>You have not entered your $your_model current odometer reading yet</span><br>";
                }

                if (isset($_POST['odo']) && isset($_POST['selectAModel']))
                {
                        $odo = sanitizeString($_POST['odo']);
                        if ($odo != "")
                        {
                                $time = time();
                                queryMysql("UPDATE cars SET odo = '$odo', time = '$time' WHERE user = '$user' AND model = '$your_model'");
                        }

                }

                echo <<<_END
                        <form method='post' action='car_test.php?view=$view'>
                                <input type='text' id='odo' name='odo'>
                                <label for='odo'>Current Odometer Reading</label><br>
                                <input data-transition='slide' type='submit' value='Submit Odometer Reading'>
                        </form>
                _END;

                echo "<br>";

                date_default_timezone_get();

                if (isset($_GET['erase']))
                {
                        $erase = sanitizeString($_GET['erase']);
                        queryMysql("DELETE FROM car WHERE odo='$erase' AND user='$user'");
                }

                $query = "SELECT * FROM car WHERE user='$view' ORDER BY time DESC";
                $result = queryMysql($query);
                $num = $result->num_rows;

                for ($j = 0; $j < $num; ++$j)
                {

                        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                        if ($row['odo'] != "" && $row['user'] == $user)
                        {
                                echo date('M jS \'y g:ia:', $row['time']);
                                echo "<br><br>";
                                echo "<a href='car.php?view=" . $row['user'] . "'>" . $row['user']. "</a>";
                                echo "<br>";
                                echo "last oil change was at: " . $row['odo'] . "<br>";

                                $current_odo = ((int) $row['odo']);

                                $eight_thousand = 8000;

                                $next_change = $current_odo + $eight_thousand;

                                echo "your next oil change is at: $next_change";

                                if ($row['user'] == $user)
                                        echo "<br><br>[<a href='car.php?view=$view" . "&erase=" . $row['odo'] . "'>erase</a>]";

                                echo "<br><br><br>";
                        }
                }

        }

?>
        </div><br>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: First of all clear your concept about echoing a variable. If you echo in double quote you can write variable directly or inside curly braces. If you're using single quote then you can write directly within single quote.
`echo "Here is {$variable} example";` and 
`echo "Here is $variable example";` and `echo "Here is ".$variable." example";`  and `echo 'Here is '.$variable.' example';`

These are correct syntax.

Comment: Murad, I'm not sure what echoing the value of $your_model has to do with my issue. My issue is where the value of $your_model disappears once i click the submit button. Once I click the submit button to send my Odometer reading to MySQL, it is supposed to pass in the value of $your_model to MySQL, but when MySQL receives the query, $your_model is always empty

Comment: Web requests are stateless. That is a fundamental concept about web development which you need to ensure you understand properly. If you submitted the form containing the model in a previous request than the request containing the odometer reading then its value will not be persisted on the next request. Either put both fields in one form and submit them together or take steps to preserve / pass on the model value in subsequent requests - e.g. put it in the Session and then retrieve it, or put the model value into a hidden  field on the odometer form.

Comment: ADyson, thank you so much for giving me direction...What you just responded with kind of makes sense to me. I'm new to PHP so please bear with me. So, if I have a car model stored in $your_model, do I then do something like $_SESSION['id'] = $your_model; then then do $my_car_model = $_SESSION['$your_model']; ? Again, I'm trying to get the hang of PHP and what I just wrote probably didn't make much sense, but I do kind of feel like I see what you're trying to tell me is the issue..a little more guidance would be greatly appreciated. Also, I already have a session started in header.php

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Comment: Hello Dharman, I am in development mode, this is not production...I plan on doing prepared statements once I get the other concepts working first, thanks.

Comment: @ginbosqueeze, you are sending a request that is setting up `$your_model` and again you are sending another request that will definitely make `$your_model` undefined, in this case, you have to use session, on first request set the value of `$your_model` in your session, then you can get that session in next request(s).

Comment: `do I then do something like $_SESSION['id'] = $your_model ... `...if you want do session storage then yes that makes sense. Do the storing step when $your_model is defined. And then retrieve it from the Session instead when you're submitting the odometer value.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have attempted all of your suggestions, I have set the session variable in the places you guys have told me to, and have also tried placing it in other places...the variable still disappears when I hit the submit button on my odometer field. I did however rewrite the code to put both fields in the same form, but then now I have to figure a way to grab some other information that is getting data from the database real time. I honestly wanted the session portion to work because I feel that is the best/correct way of doing so. I decided to maybe write to a file and read :(

Comment: Also I attempted the hidden field suggestion from ADyson, with no luck. My code is a simple straightfoward one, it would have been great if someone could somehow recreate it to see what's happening, but if not that is fine. Learning to use the session correctly would have been exciting for me. Unless someone can show me an example similar to my code that works, I think I'll look to just store the drop down menu selection in a file and then read that file to get it's content and display it. Hopefully I can get that to work. Thanks for all of you help and consideration, it is greatly appreciated

Comment: _"I plan on doing prepared statements once I get the other concepts working first"_... oh the number of times I've heard this. Prepared statements aren't some "advanced mode" technique. They are fundamental. Not only that, you make fewer mistakes with parameter binding; they are literally the easier option

Comment: Phil is right. And also why go to the effort of writing (and testing) the same functionality twice?? As Phil says, it's not any more difficult to do it the correct way first time round - and it's less prone to silly errors. Next time, save yourself the trouble and just use prepared statements from the start.

Comment: Without seeing what you actually did, in detail, it's hard to know why either of your approaches failed. Those are both very common approaches, in use in millions of web applications every day, and should work correctly. I'll write you an example using the Session approach (since that doesn't require you to change your UI, if you don't want to). You shouldn't need to resort to file storage (and anyway that really won't scale up at all when you have multiple users on the site)

Answer (score 1):

Web requests are *stateless*. They do not automatically remember anything from one request to the next. Each time you load a page, or post a form, or send an AJAX request to your server, a PHP script runs from the beginning of the requested script, and acts as if it had never been run before. This has some advantages, but one obvious downside is that it doesn't preserve any variable values.

To get round this, you have to take specific steps to preserve the data you want to keep between requests, either for a particular user or to store in general, and then retrieve it when you need it.

In your scenario, you have two forms, one for the model and one for the odometer data. This means there will be two separate requests to the server. So if you submitted the form containing the model in one request, then in the request containing the odometer reading the model value will not be available.

You could either put both fields in one form and submit them together or take steps to preserve / pass on the model value in subsequent requests - e.g. put it in the Session and then retrieve it, or put the model value into a hidden field on the odometer form.

Here's a simple example of how you could use the Session for this:

```
<?php
session_start(); //remember to use this to enable Session usage in your script
require_once 'header.php';

//...etc, until you get to

if (isset($_POST['selectAModel'])) 
  $your_model = sanitizeString($_POST['selectAModel']);
  $_SESSION["your_model"] = $your_model; //add the model data to the session
}

//then we get to:
//if (isset($_POST['odo']) && isset($_POST['selectAModel'])) - this can't work because both POST values won't exist at the same time. Replace it with:

if (isset($_POST['odo']))
{
  if (isset($_SESSION["your_model"])) {
    $your_model = $_SESSION["your_model"];
  }
  else 
  { 
    die("No valid model value set, cannot proceed to save odometer reading");
  }

  //...etc
```

Comment: Hello Phil and ADyson, you guys are awesome! Thanks much for the insight, I definitely will look to edit my code they way you advised me to, and I will report back with my findings...again, thank you guys very much for your diligence and patience, this community is very helpful and effective because of guys like you all.

Comment: Thanks ADyson, I was able to get it to work! I appreciate the help!